# Scala: cannot load scala script with arguments

Tags: scala

I am studying Scala and I am using Scala for win 10

I have write a script "helloarg.scala" with 1 line `println("Hello, " + args(0) + "!")`

When i used cmd to run file (not in scala shell), it worked.

```
C:\Users\Darkntnt>scala D:\Scala\helloarg.scala planet

Hello, planet!
```

However, It got the error when i load file from scala shell

```
Error:
scala> :load D:\Scala\helloarg.scala planet

usage: :load -v file
```

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good one.

`:load` doesn't respect args; there are a few different idioms for "run an app as a script".

I'll add this example to the issue about unifying them.

As a workaround, maybe `val args = Array("planet")` or similar.